# Confused on vector analysis notation: ($\cdot \mid \cdot)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

> Which of the following statements for scalar fields $Φ$ and $Ψ$ is correct? Justify the correctness of the true statements.
>
> 1. $\operatorname{div}\color{red}{\big(}\phi \operatorname{grad} (\psi)\color{red}{\mid}\psi \operatorname{grad} (\phi)\color{red}{\big)}=\phi \operatorname{div} (\operatorname{grad}(\psi))-\psi \operatorname{div} ( \operatorname{grad} (\phi))$
> 2. $\operatorname{\Delta} (\phi \operatorname{grad}(\psi)-\psi \operatorname{grad}(\phi))=\phi \operatorname{div}(\psi)-\psi \operatorname{div}(\psi)$
> 3. $\operatorname{div}(\phi \operatorname{grad}(\psi)-\psi \operatorname{grad}(\phi))=\phi \operatorname{\Delta} \psi - \psi \operatorname{\Delta} \phi $
> 4. $\color{red}{\big(}\operatorname{\nabla} \color{red}{\mid} \phi \operatorname{grad}(\psi)-\psi \operatorname{grad} (\phi)\color{red}{\big)}=\phi(\operatorname{\nabla} \times \psi)-\psi(\operatorname{\nabla} \times \phi)$

What I did:

2. false: $\operatorname{\Delta} \cdot  \operatorname{grad} f\neq \operatorname{div}(f)$
3. false: $\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{grad}f)=\operatorname{\nabla} f\neq \operatorname{\Delta} f$

Questions:
Can someone tell me is this correct and help me  with the 1. and 4.?

I dont understand what exactly $|$ means here. I find that $|$ could mean "*such that*", "*restricted of*".. But I don't know how to use it here.

Comment: No clue what the | would mean in the context of vector calculus. My guess would be inner product a la some weird variant of bra-ket notation, but that doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Also, div(grad(f)) is indeed $\Delta f$. $\nabla f$ is just another way of writing $grad(f)$.

Comment: Do you know what the notations stand for interms of "dell" and "nabla" operators ?

Comment: Yes I know. | is confusing me.

Comment: The notation $(\cdot\mid\cdot)$ is indeed one way of writing the inner product.  I've seen it in some translated Russian texts.  Notice in both cases you have a vector (or vector operator) on each side of the $\mid$.

Comment: It makes more sense with the typo corrections that @Bye_World made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your professor/ book is using the notation $(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ to mean the inner product:

1. On the LHS is the divergence of the inner product of two vector fields.  But the inner product of two vector fields is a scalar field and one can't take the divergence of a scalar field. Thus without even looking at the other side this can't be a correct identity because the LHS is undefined.
2. The RHS now has the divergence of a scalar field and is thus undefined.
3. This one is correct.  $$\require{cancel}\operatorname{div}(\phi \operatorname{grad}(\psi)-\psi \operatorname{grad}(\phi))=\phi\operatorname{\Delta}\psi +\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{(\operatorname{grad}(\phi)\mid \operatorname{grad}(\psi))}}} - \psi\operatorname{\Delta}\phi -\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{(\operatorname{grad}(\psi)\mid \operatorname{grad}(\phi))}}}= \phi \operatorname{\Delta} \psi - \psi \operatorname{\Delta} \phi$$
4. The LHS is just an uncommon way of writing the divergence of a vector field and is thus a scalar field.  On the RHS however you have a vector field.  Thus LHS and RHS are different *types* of objects and cannot be equal.